# How can I search for posts by Deleted Users?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, search, deleted-accounts

I want this option a lot. How? For example, moz got deleted in a SE site with a lot of excellent answers but user:moz returns /dev/null.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to search. With irony, I can find all your posts here with:

```sql
select 
   id as [Post Link]
  ,body
  ,owneruserid
  ,ownerdisplayname
from posts 
where ownerdisplayname = 'user131971'
```

Alternatively, you can find all posts by any deleted user with:

```sql
select 
   id as [Post Link]
  ,body
  ,owneruserid
  ,ownerdisplayname
from posts 
where owneruserid is null
```

Answer (score 2):

If a user is deleted, then while you can see his name, you are unable to search for his posts.  Advanced searches are done based on a user number, so it would be interesting to know if you knew that number if the search would still work.  If so, then maybe, they could have the number as mouseover on the username, so that you could search that way.

If a user requests to be deleted, they will sometimes remove his name completely, and replace it with `UserXXXXX`, in which case they actually could still use the same id/mouseover paradigm.

Comment: Not [here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4317/most-favoriable-collision-with-a-car-how-should-i-act-before-collision-supposin/4323#4323). I can still see Moz but I cannot find his profile or his questions anymore. I want to find his answers. (Ps. I could have choosen any other user, the example is irrelevant. I want this option over SE sites). And what is this UserXXXXX? How can I then identify posts by users if they are labelled UserXXXXXXX?

Comment: Well, you got me, I guess they do it differently on different sites.  The behavior I describe is what happened to my posts on Programmers when I pulled out.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I find it quite insulting to label deleted users with UserXXXXX, like some mass, but like here moz did provide excellent answers and now searching is almost impossible. Without the little marking "moz", it would be totally impossible. The site is useless now without proper search.

Comment: Sometimes users don't want to keep their name attached.  In my case I didn't care, I just didn't want to see notifications from that site.

Comment: Good point, sorry I did not consider that option. Indeed.

Comment: I thought that the userXXXXXX format was only used for unregistered users. There are plenty of examples of posts from deleted users on MSO and SO that don't follow that pattern. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80231/why-do-you-participate-in-newsgroups-fora), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37567/notifications-closed), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324/how-can-i-convert-a-hexadecimal-number-to-base-10-efficiently-in-c), etc.

Comment: Anonymizing an account prior to deletion is usually only done for self-requested deletions.